# How to deserialize object of specific type from JSON in Java if it was serialized to JSON as Object?

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I'm new in Java!

My goal:
I have collection of Objects which lets me to keep objects of any types by some key (like Map) (put them to it and get from). I can add objects of any type to it (for example I can add object of MyClass). Then I serialize this object to separate string in JSON format using GSON (then I can serialize this string to separate file, for example). When I want to get some object back I request it from collection by key and collection deserializes corresponding string to Object object and return me it. Then I cast it to MyClass to be able to use this object.

The code below skips work with the collection:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object myClass = new MyClass(); //imitation of putting MyClass object to Collection
    String json = gson.toJson(myClass); //serializing to JSON
    Object myClass1 = gson.fromJson(json, Object.class); //imitation of deserializing and getting object from collection
    Main.MyClass myClass2 = (Main.MyClass) myClass1;
```

The last string of this code throws java.lang.ClassCastException, because "gson.fromJson(json, Object.class);" returns object of type "com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap"

How I can reach my goal???

Comment: I might be very wrong but have you tried `Main.MyClass myClass2 = gson.fromJson(json, Main.MyClass.class);`?

Comment: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#serializing-and-deserializing-collection-with-objects-of-arbitrary-types

Answer (score 2):

This might be because when you use `gson.fromJson(json, Object.class)`, you cast it to an object and not to your MyClass, maybe if you use `gson.fromJson(json, MyClass.class)` and then cast it that it will return the correct values. Otherwise they will make a simple object class.

Comment: Yes. I see that `MyClass` is an inner class; so just make sure it's `static`.

Answer (score 0):

`gson.fromJson(json, Object.class);` cast to LinkedTreeMap (see gson sources at `ObjectTypeAdapter.read(JsonReader in)`).

Try this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Object myClass = new MyClass(); //imitation of putting MyClass object to Collection
String json = gson.toJson(myClass); //serializing to JSON
Main.MyClass myClass2 = gson.fromJson(json, Main.MyClass.class);
```